# How to get text field value in html forms django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I made a template in html for my Django app.

Inside my template I have a field name taking `bid amount` from user.

I want to get that value in any variable and want to pass it into url.

The template is the following:

```
Bid amount:<input type="text" name="txtJob" >

                <form method="POST" action="submitbid/?project_id={{project.project_id}}"
                >


            {{bid.text}}" class="button">Submit your bid</a> -->
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="bid now" />
                        <!-- Provide a button to click to submit the form. -->


                </form>
```

I used `var amount = document.getElementById('txtJob').value;`
but it prints on frontend (browser)

Answer (score 0):

Define the input field inside your `form` and 
its value is automatically submitted using the POST method.